# What component from Access Database Engine 2007 affects ActiveX?

Tags: forms, ms-access, database-connection, activex

I have some programs with MS Access connections, using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider.
After last Office update (version 16.0.11629.20246) they start failing, so i tried execute AccessDatabaseEngine 2007 (version 12.0.4518.1014) and they returns to work.

But now the forms components appears unconfigured (with some kind of glitch) during runtime, one of this glitchs for example are diminished labels and edits. I think that some component installed within AccessDatabaseEngine is affecting the ActiveX.

Above are the references that i'm using in one of these programs.

```
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#..\..\..\..\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
Reference=*\G{00000200-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}#2.0#0#..\..\..\..\Arquivos de programas\Arquivos comuns\system\ado\msado20.tlb#Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library
Reference=*\G{6B263850-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\WINDOWS\system32\MSSTDFMT.DLL#Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library
Object=Excel.Sheet.8; EXCEL.EXE
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0; mscomctl.OCX
Object={8E27C92E-1264-101C-8A2F-040224009C02}#7.0#0; MSCAL.OCX
Object={86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCT2.OCX
Object={65E121D4-0C60-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCHRT20.OCX
```

Anyone have an ideia what component is affecting ActiveX?
And if exist another way to install and test Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider without AccessDatabaseEngine 2007?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"Access Error: Query is corrupt." is a known bug introduced with the latest Security Update...if you have Access 2016 there is a patch but everyone else has to wait till 12 Dec.
The workaround is to rename the "problematic" tables to something like "OriginalTableName_tbl" and create simple queries with the same name as the Original table (the query is named : *OriginalTableName*) and SQL :

```
Select * From OriginalTableName_tbl
```

Now you can continue working

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, but the real problem is when i install or reinstall AccessDatabaseEngine 2007 to have Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, the forms and components of my programs are misconfiguring.